How to retrieve values form csv file in Netlogo?
I'm using the CSV extension in Netlogo to bring numbers from a table. This file has a header and just one column with 1700 rows.
Each tick I have needs to grab the next number from the CSV table.
Example:
Table
67,
81,
54

for tick 1 set precipitation 67

for tick 2 set precipitation 81

for tick 3 set precipitation 54

and so on
How to do this?

An example is on the Official Help Page of the Extension, demonstrating how to extract values from a table with a single column. See the modified version below, including the suggestion of @SteveRailsback of using first to avoid the list output.
extensions [csv]

globals [ precipitation  ]

to setup
  clear-all
  file-close-all ; Close any files open from last run
  file-open "test.csv"  
  set precipitation  csv:from-row file-read-line ; use it once to skip the header
  ; other setup goes here
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  if file-at-end? [ stop ]
  set precipitation first csv:from-row file-read-line
  tick
end

If you have a table with multiple columns I recommend storing the table headers and using it to identify the column index.
extensions [csv]

globals [
  csv_headers
  precipitation
  other_var
]

to setup
  clear-all
  file-close-all ; Close any files open from last run
  file-open "test.csv"
  set csv_headers  csv:from-row file-read-line ; store headers to find right column
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  if file-at-end? [ stop ]
  let current_line csv:from-row file-read-line ; read the full line
  set precipitation item (position  "precipitation" csv_headers) current_line ; pick value from column with precipitation header
  set other_var item (position  "other_var" csv_headers) current_line ; repeat for another variable
  tick
end


Thank you so much for the help, quick question, I dont understand how to call different columns. At this time I dont need but it could come in handy. Ley say my excel file has precipitation and temperature

I added a multi-column approach to my answer and further adjusted the code for the single-column according to the suggestion by @SteveRailsback

Thank you, this for sure will come in handy. I just have a quick question, in the multiple column,  why does the csv:from-row file-read-line at setup only gets the header but the csv:from-row file-read-line gets all the table? Sorry to keep asking when you already solved the issue. Thanks

so it is a combination of two commands an does both times the same. file-read-line reads the next line from the opened file (file-open). So no matter where you call it, it will give you the next line (so one row with all columns) that hasn't been read yet. csv:from-row then converts the string returned by file-read-line into a list.

The previous answer is good, except: Remember that csv:from-row produces a list, not a number. The precipitation number will be the only item on that list. To get the precipitation number, you will need:
set precipitation first (csv:from-row file-read-line)

Right! I adjusted my answer accordingly. Thanks for the suggestion!
